# Magento 2 add multiple classes php file in module

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I am working on a magento 2 payment module but i am stuck at a point i need to include a third party payment gateway php file in which multiple classes are declared like class a, class b, class c in class.php file 
i am using require_once('magento_path/class.php') ; 
but it seems not working 
please help!

--Updated-- here is my sample of code to place request to gateway--
Note : All Variables are just for example

```
     public function placeRequest(TransferInterface $transferObject)
            {
                require_once ("ThePaymentGateway/PaymentSystem.php");
                $rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList = new RequestGatewayEntryPointList();
$rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList->add("gw1.".$PaymentProcessorFullDomain, 100, 1);
                $rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList->add("https://gw2.".$PaymentProcessorFullDomain, 200, 1);
                $rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList->add("https://gw3.".$PaymentProcessorFullDomain, 300, 1);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction = new CardDetailsTransaction($rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList);

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getMerchantAuthentication()->setMerchantID($MerchantID);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getMerchantAuthentication()->setPassword($Password);

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getMessageDetails()->setTransactionType("SALE");

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getAmount()->setValue($Amount);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->setOrderID($OrderID);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->setOrderDescription($OrderDescription);

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getEchoCardType()->setValue(true);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getEchoAmountReceived()->setValue(true);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getEchoAVSCheckResult()->setValue(true);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getEchoCV2CheckResult()->setValue(true);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getThreeDSecureOverridePolicy()->setValue(true);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getTransactionControl()->getDuplicateDelay()->setValue(60);

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getThreeDSecureBrowserDetails()->getDeviceCategory()->setValue(0);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getThreeDSecureBrowserDetails()->setAcceptHeaders("*/*");
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getTransactionDetails()->getThreeDSecureBrowserDetails()->setUserAgent($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCardDetails()->setCardName($CardName);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCardDetails()->setCardNumber($CardNumber);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCardDetails()->setIssueNumber($IssueNumber);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCardDetails()->setCV2($CV2);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setAddress1($Address1);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setAddress2($Address2);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setAddress3($Address3);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setAddress4($Address4);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setCity($City);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setState($State);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->getBillingAddress()->setPostCode($PostCode);
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->setEmailAddress("test@test.com");
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->setPhoneNumber("123456789");
            $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->getCustomerDetails()->setCustomerIPAddress($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

            $boTransactionProcessed = $cdtCardDetailsTransaction->processTransaction($cdtrCardDetailsTransactionResult, $todTransactionOutputData);
            if ($boTransactionProcessed == false)
                {
                    // could not communicate with the payment gateway 
                    $NextFormMode = "PAYMENT_FORM";
                    $Message = "Couldn't communicate with payment gateway";
                    PaymentFormHelper::reportTransactionResults($OrderID, 30, $Message, null);
                }
                else
                {
                 echo "Payment Success";
                }
       }
```

All the payment gateway classes are defined in Paymentsystem.php provided by payzone but here require_once seems not working

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a method to develop your own custom modules. If you don't follow this method then you'll have path errors like the one you're talking about, specially within the payment module where you have tons of validations and security manners.

I'll suggest to check out this page. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/page/3/

He made a framework called PESTLE that makes so much easier to creates custom modules http://alanstorm.com/magento2_pestle_code_generation/

Check them out.

Comment: I create custom payment module to connect with payzone payment gateway but payzone provides a php library which needs to be include in my module for connections but the library contains so many classes defined in one php file so my question is how can i include this file in my module?

Comment: Ok I see. Well I'd add those classes to my block file. You can create classes within the same php file. Whenever you'd like to use them, initiate them by creating a new instance $newClass = new Class A ... Then when ever you'd like to use a method from this object, you can do $newClass->method();   If you want learn about namespace with that you can add this classes thru dependency injection in your block __construct, so you can follow the Magento way. Just Namespace the new classes within the same Block file